# Is there an easy way to apply logging (e.g. Zend_Log) to Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller

I've got an application which seems to be stuck in a redirect loop when I put it in a subdirectory of my server (e.g. blah.com/testing/ instead of blah.com/), despite sharing the same code. I think I've handled the redirection stuff incorrectly, but Apache's debugging output doesn't actually list the redirections, because they're being handled inside PHP.

Is there an easy way to attach a logger to the redirection function?

Comment: if you are using redirect helper of zf not 'forward' then you can see all kind of redirects taking place from firebug NET panel in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector
{
    protected function _redirect($url)
    {
        $this->myPrettyLoggingFunction();
        parent::_redirect($url);
    }
}
```

if `My_` namespace configured right, this plugin will be loaded by `PluginLoader` instead of default `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector`

usage - standard way `$this->_helper->redirector(...)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this needs to be `direct` instead of `_redirect`. But I could be wrong. +1